# Coordinate transform given $r$,$\theta$, $\dot\theta$, $\ddot\theta$,

Tags: transformation, polar-coordinates

given $r$,$\theta$, $\dot\theta$, $\ddot\theta$ I need to find $x$,$y$,$v_x$,$v_y$,$a_x$,$a_y$, what are the equations for those variables?

$\dot r = 0$

Comment: You need to add more to this. As written, I cannot make out anything. What is $v,x,y,a$ in relation to $r,\theta$, etc?

Comment: @FaraadArmwood  $x$ is the position in the $x$ direction under Cartesian coordinates, $v_x$ is the $x$ component of velocity, $a_x$the $x$ component of acceleration,  same for the $y$ components of velocity and acceleration.

Comment: You mean $x=r\cos\theta$ and $y=r\sin\theta$?

Comment: @CYKwong Correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not very sure about the meaning of your symbols. But if my understanding is correct. Then I have

$$x=r\cos\theta$$

$$y=r\sin\theta$$

$$v_x=\dot r\cos\theta+r(-\sin\theta)\dot\theta=-r\dot\theta\sin\theta$$

$$v_y=\dot r\sin\theta+r(\cos\theta)\dot\theta=r\dot\theta\cos\theta$$

$$a_x=-\dot r\dot\theta\sin\theta-r\ddot\theta\sin\theta-r\dot\theta(\cos\theta)\dot\theta=-r\ddot\theta\sin\theta-r(\dot\theta)^2\cos\theta$$

$$a_y=\dot r\dot\theta\cos\theta+r\ddot\theta\cos\theta+r\dot\theta(-\sin\theta)\dot\theta=r\ddot\theta\cos\theta-r(\dot\theta)^2\sin\theta$$

Comment: That is exactly correct. Sorry, was using physics notation